# Bit shifting on non contiguous internal number representation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, arbitrary-precision

I am writing a c++ arbitrary integer library as an homework. I represented numbers internally as a vector of unsigned int, in base 10^n, where n is as big as possible while fitting into a single unsigned int digit.

I made this choice as a trade-off between space, performance and digit access (it allows me to have much better performances than using base 10, without adding any complexity when converting to a human readable string).

So for example:

base10(441243123294967295) 18 digits

base1000000000(441243123,294967295) 2 digits (comma separated)

Internal representation with uint32

[00011010 01001100 11010101 11110011] [00010001 10010100 11010111 11111111]

To complete the homework I have to implement bit shifting and other bitwise operators.
Does it make sense to implement shift for a number with such an internal representation?

Should I change to a base 2^n so that all bits of the internal representation are significative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can*, but you do not *have to*: bit shifting will double the number, no matter what base you use for *interpreting* it later, because internally these `int`s are still interpreted as binary by the underlying shift operations. Your implementation will have to decide on the tradeoff there, because your shifting will become harder to implement. On the other hand, the printing in base-10 will remain simpler.

Another solution favoring the decimal system that you may consider is using [*binary-coded decimals (BCD)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). Back in the day, hardware used to accelerate these operations (e.g. 6502, the CPU of Apple-2) included special instructions for adding bytes in the BCD interpretation. You would have to implement special correction if you use this representation, but it may be a worthy learning exercise.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I change to a base 2^n so that all bits of the internal representation are significative?

Most definitely yes!

Not only that, but modern-day computers in general are all about base2. If this is an excercise, you'll most likely want to learn how to do it well.

Answer (score 1):

All libraries for this kind uses base 2. They do that for a reason: faster processing, possibility for bitwise operations, more compact storage, and more. These advantages outweights the difficulty to covert to decimal. Therefore it's highly recommended that you convert to binary.